# How can I dynamically build an array from ranges in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm working in Google Sheets, and I want to use a range of cells, each one with a sheet name in it, to build an array out of the rows on each referenced sheet. But I want the array to remain dynamic so that when I change the source range the array will update on its own.

My workbook is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZM1jJxzAMF9APKfOu3Au3UWKV34EEMgsoY0Z6b1zHY/edit?usp=sharing). I'm trying to build a template worksheet for Weekends and Weekdays (Sheet: Weekday Template), where I can select blocks using dropdowns (from sheet: Lists). And then on each Day's Program sheet (Sheet: Monday Program), it populates using rows from the Block sheets (Sheet: Morning Music Block).

I've cheated on Wednesday's Program (Sheet: Wednesday Program), I've manually made it the way I want. But had to use an unsustainable formula:

`=query({'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Antonye Holyde Block'!B3:D;'Mike Macintosh Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Morning Music Block'!B3:D;'Joe Focht Block'!B3:D;'Skip Heitzig Block'!B3:D;'Pancho Juarez Block'!B3:D;'Damian Kyle Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Afternoon Music Block'!B3:D;'J. Vernon McGee Block'!B3:D;'Mike Macintosh Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Evening Music Block'!B3:D;'Joe Focht Block'!B3:D;'J. Vernon McGee Block'!B3:D;'Skip Heitzig Block'!B3:D;'Pancho Juarez Block'!B3:D;'Damian Kyle Block'!B3:D;'Antonye Holyde Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

I can generate that ghastly array refference text with:

`=join(";",ArrayFormula("'"&If(A1,query({indirect("'"&D1&" Modifier'!D2:D")},"Select * where Col1 is not null "),query({'Weekday Template'!D2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null "))&" Block'!B3:D"))`

(And I have that hidden in 'Monday Program'!C1, for reference.)

But when I try to insert this array built from queries, into a query, I get the outer query trying to run against the text, and not following the references at all.

`=query({join(";",ArrayFormula("'"&If(A1,query({indirect("'"&D1&" Modifier'!D2:D")},"Select * where Col1 is not null "),query({'Weekday Template'!D2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null "))&" Block'!B3:D"))},"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

Outputs:

`'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Antonye Holyde Block'!B3:D;'Mike Macintosh Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Morning Music Block'!B3:D;'Joe Focht Block'!B3:D;'Skip Heitzig Block'!B3:D;'Pancho Juarez Block'!B3:D;'Damian Kyle Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Afternoon Music Block'!B3:D;'J. Vernon McGee Block'!B3:D;'Mike Macintosh Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Evening Music Block'!B3:D;'Joe Focht Block'!B3:D;'J. Vernon McGee Block'!B3:D;'Skip Heitzig Block'!B3:D;'Pancho Juarez Block'!B3:D;'Damian Kyle Block'!B3:D;'Antonye Holyde Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D`

And trying it a different way:

`=query({indirect("'"&If(A1,query({indirect("'"&D1&" Modifier'!D2:D")},"Select * where Col1 is not null "),query({'Weekday Template'!D2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null "))&" Block'!B3:D")},"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

Outputs:

```
Interrupt   Station ID          Serial:ID
Spot        Promo               Album:%Block%
Fill        The Word of Promise Serial:TWoP;Announce:5
Spot        Sandy Adams         Serial:Sandy;Album:%Block%
Fill        Music               Genre:Worship
```

This is a correct but partial result, it only queries the first of my 39 ranges.

Not even:

`=ArrayFormula(indirect("{"&join(";","'"&If(A1,query({indirect("'"&D1&" Modifier'!D2:D")},"Select * where Col1 is not null "),query({'Weekday Template'!D2:D},"Select * where Col1 is not null "))&" Block'!B3:D")&"}"))`

...works. It just says:

`Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is '{'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Antonye Holyde Block'!B3:D;'Mike Macintosh Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Morning Music Block'!B3:D;'Joe Focht Block'!B3:D;'Skip Heitzig Block'!B3:D;'Pancho Juarez Block'!B3:D;'Damian Kyle Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Afternoon Music Block'!B3:D;'J. Vernon McGee Block'!B3:D;'Mike Macintosh Block'!B3:D;'Sam Allen Block'!B3:D;'Chuck Smith Block'!B3:D;'Greg Laurie Block'!B3:D;'Jon Courson Block'!B3:D;'Evening Music Block'!B3:D;'Joe Focht Block'!B3:D;'J. Vernon McGee Block'!B3:D;'Skip Heitzig Block'!B3:D;'Pancho Juarez Block'!B3:D;'Damian Kyle Block'!B3:D;'Antonye Holyde Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D;'Bible Reading NKJV Block'!B3:D}'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.`

Can anyone help me solve this without resorting to App Scripts?

Answer (score 0):

in Google Sheets `INDIRECT` does not support multiple cell/range references. each range (like in your case) needs to be wrapped in individual `INDIRECT`and then the array can be constructed like:

```
={INDIRECT(range1); INDIRECT(range2); etc}
```

a solution in your case would be to generate a passive array in some helper cell and then copy-paste it into the active formula either manually or with some script

Comment: Thank you! Just knowing that indirect for sure can't work with arrays means I can stop banging my head against the wall. I'll have to look at this differently now.

Comment: I've taken a completely different approach, and Monday looks good to me now. I've filled each column with a duplicate formula, and the duplication handles what I'd hoped arrays and queries would. The time column is: ```=Filter('Weekday Template'!C$2:C,'Weekday Template'!E$2:E<=Row()-2,'Weekday Template'!F$2:F>=Row()-2)``` and the other columns are just: ```=indirect ("'"&Filter('Weekday Template'!$D$2:$D,'Weekday Template'!$E$2:$E<=Row()-2,'Weekday Template'!$F$2:$F>=Row()-2)&" Block'!B"&2+counta(filter($B$3:$B3,$B$3:$B3=$B3)))``` So I ended up putting all the logic inside the indirect.